# Eclipse: How can I make Ctrl+F11 work no matter which file is being edited?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> is the "Run" keyboard shortcut in Eclipse.

But for me, that only works if a Main class is active in the editor. For any of the other 100+ java files in my workspace, eclipse pops up a dialog, complaining "Editor does not contain a main type".

This makes the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> shortcut nearly useless. I either have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, name of main class, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>, or use the mouse.

Do I have something misconfigured? What can I do to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> really run my program, no matter which file is active in the editor? Or is everybody using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> shortcut like that?

edit: I'm using eclipse 3.5.0

Comment: **if you have a Microsoft 4000 keyboard** --> check to see if the `F Lock` is enabled or not --> if the `F lock` is not enabled the `F11` key will actually be mapped to a different keyboard event... you need to enable `F lock` and try again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check the preferences, Launching section - you may want to switch from "launch selection" to "launch previously launched application".

Comment: And this is because that this was the original behavior but for some reason they changed it to the current behavior (which is close to useless) .

Answer (score 22):

You can configure Eclipse to always use the previously launched application: *Window → Preferences → Run/Debug → Launching → Always launch the previously launched application*. This almost always does what you want.

Comment: Nice! For those who may not know, this also works for the STS IDE  (SpringSourceToolSuite) which uses eclipse as its foundation.

Comment: I tried this, hoping to be able to launch an Android project from while on an XML file from the project, but this didn't work for me. Suggestion?