# Make Ctrl+F11 launch Android project even when on XML file

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> on Eclipse is a life saver. Unfortunately, it only works when the currently selected file tab is of a `.java` file. It doesn't work when the currently selected file tab is of an `.xml` file.

I searched this great SO resource and found something [very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213075/eclipse-how-can-i-make-ctrlf11-work-no-matter-which-file-is-being-edited) to what I am looking for but unfortunately the [solution offered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213075/eclipse-how-can-i-make-ctrlf11-work-no-matter-which-file-is-being-edited/2213082#2213082) simply doesn't work for XML in an Android project.

Is there a way to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> launch Android project even when on XML file?

This is my current preferences dialog windows:

[image]

**Update:** This mysteriously started working. I have no idea how this happened (I didn't change anything in the Eclipse, except for existing Eclipse and restarting it).

Comment: That answer should work... just make sure to launch from some Java file in your project at some point before you try to launch from the XML file.

Comment: I never got it to work properly, not that i tried very hard, but somehow it wasn't obvious.

Comment: @Phonon It somehow started working. Is it possible that for this change to *really* apply, Eclipse needs to be re-started?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering myself (after about 4 months): There isn't a way to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> launch Android project even when on XML file.

A currently working workaround is to select a .java file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>), then run the project's exec via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Alternatively, if you need to see the LogCat while the program is running, inject a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> in between, i.e.:

1. Select a .java file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>),
2. Switch to DDMS perspective (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>)
3. Run the project's exec via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Anything to avoid lifting hand from the keyboard... ;)

Comment: *Anything to avoid lifting hand from the keyboard...* — You must be a ThinkPad trackpoint user like I am :)

Answer (score 58):

This fixed the problem for me.

Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Launch Operation -> Always Launch the previously launched application

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder why eclipse wouldn't keep this by default for Android.

Comment: A long while back this was the default in Eclipse, and now after Luna release, this option is default again.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, which pops up an Android specific menu. Then press <kbd>R</kbd> or select `Run` with the mouse.

Comment: Clever! On a side note: This is the Android-specific equivalent of the standard Alt+Shift+X and Alt+Shift+D (which unfortunately doesn't run nor debug Android).